# Print pivot table like it shows in ipython-notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

When I show a pivot table in IPython Notebook, it shows in a really good format with cellular format. But when I try to print in in terminal, it doesn't show so well.

I have tried:
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
- print(pivot_table)
- display(pivot_table)
- HTML(pivot_table.to_html())

All above methods don't give the results as they like in IPython Notebook. Any suggestions?

Comment: Terminals cannot generally display HTML.